# winrm.exceptions.WinRMTransportError: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 403

Tags: python, powershell, remote-access, winrm

I am trying to connect to remote Windows server and run PowerShell commands on it using **pywinrm**, but I keep receiving a 403 HTTP bad response code.

I have disabled firewall and tried running "winrm quickconfig" on the windows server but the issue is still persisiting.

What can I do to solve it?

Comment: See powershell code at following : https://pypi.org/project/pywinrm/